# Is it safe to eat chili sauce when some dried around neck on brand new bottle?

Tags: food-safety

I opened a new jar of chili sauce and there was a dark hard substance on the rim and inside lid in same spot, like some of the sauce was there when the lid was placed and sealed. There was none inside the jar and the jar seemed to have been sealed properly because the lid popped when I opened it. The use by date was good as well. Is the sauce safe to consume?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the popping of the lid, I would assume the jar was sealed properly despite the residue. I believe its probably some kind of sauce overspill in the manufacturing processes that was missed when the lid was attached. It's probably fine to eat, but you can always contact the manufacturer to inquire. Most likely send you a replacement jar of sauce.